# I want all my numbers to be equal on cell 11 digit or add 3's Zero in front

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want all my numbers to be equal on cell , 11 digit , if there only 8 digit, must add 3 zero to make 
it equal , if there is 9 digit must add 2 zero to make it 11, it there is only 10 , must add 1 zero.

and I have 810 Rows that i have to follow that structure. I m using Excel 2007 and also 2016. Any Macros VBA code solution will be welcome

Structure :

00115168134 = 11 Digit  Good

186504031  = 9 digit     need 2 digit more
00186504031 = 11 digit

00023932110 = 11 digit with 3 zero
23932110 = 8 digit need 3 digit

Comment: Format the column `00000000000`

Answer (score 5):

Format Cells -> Number -> Custom -> Using "00000000000" as the number format code.

Or you can use the formula `=TEXT(A2,"00000000000")`

Comment: Great ! But Now I have to convert all those numbers as Striing Example 00002323930 , I want it now as String .  thank you

Comment: @WemboMulumba then use the formula. It will change the values to text.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following formula at a new column

```
=rept("0",11-len(a2))&a2
```